# using vector of vectors, pushing back integers does not work with Mac OS X

Tags: c++, vector

I am using a MacBook Air with eclipse and I declare a vector of vectors and try to push_back some integers but I get the following errors:

```
../main.cpp:31:17: error: expected expression
        base.push_back({ 0,3,4 });
                       ^
../main.cpp:32:17: error: expected expression
        base.push_back({ 1,2} );
                       ^
../main.cpp:33:17: error: expected expression
        base.push_back({ 4,5} );
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


void print_recurssion(std::vector<std::vector<int> > const &base, std::vector<int> &comb, size_t i = 0){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < base[i].size(); j++){
            comb[i] = base[i][j];

            if(i < base.size() - 1)
                print_recurssion(base, comb, i+1);
            else{
                for (size_t k = 0; k < comb.size(); k++)
                    std::cout << ((k==0) ? "" : "-") << comb[k];

                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
}


int main(){

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > base;

    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(0);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(4);

    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2.push_back(1);
    v2.push_back(2);

    std::vector<int> v3;
    v1.push_back(4);
    v1.push_back(5);

    base.push_back(v1);
    base.push_back(v2);
    base.push_back(v3);


    std::vector<int> comb(base.size());

    print_recurssion(base,comb);


    return 0;
}
```

Not sure what the problem is here, doesn't seem to print when I call the function.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b59e93655f22a2a6). What's your toolchain version, how do you call the compiler?

Comment: I use Eclipse using MacBook Air, not sure what you mean by tool chain version

Comment: Do you get the error by running the exact same piece of code?

Comment: Yes, I get the exact error

Comment: @Scooby Eclipse is an IDE, not a compiler, MacBook Air is irrelevant. You have configured a c++ compiler toolchain in your project, which is it?

Comment: @user0042 I am not sure how can I check that, I just downloaded Eclipse on MacBook Air (not my computer).

Comment: "../main.cpp:33:17:"Again, are you sure this error coming from this piece of code?

Comment: Yes, I just updated all the errors to this question

Comment: @user0042 does clang or 8.10 provide any information?

Comment: _@Scooby_ I have to agree with @DimChtz the code you show cannot produce this error message. Your code is just 14 lines long, so how would the compiler report an error at line 33??

Comment: @user0042 Okay just to convince everyone I posted everything, but the function is unrelated to the question posed.

Comment: @Scooby _"but the function is unrelated to the question posed."_ The point is you should provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the error, but so far you don't. Still [no repro](http://rextester.com/CXUO76133).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have C++11. So instead of

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> base;
base.push_back({ 0,3,4 });
```

try

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> base;
std::vector<int> v1;
v1.push_back(0);
v1.push_back(3);
v1.push_back(4);
base.push_back(v1);
```

EDIT (full code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


void print_recurssion(std::vector<std::vector<int> > const &base, std::vector<int> &comb, size_t i = 0){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < base[i].size(); j++){
            comb[i] = base[i][j];

            if(i < base.size() - 1)
                print_recurssion(base, comb, i+1);
            else{
                for (size_t k = 0; k < comb.size(); k++)
                    std::cout << ((k==0) ? "" : "-") << comb[k];

                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
}


int main(){

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > base;

    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(0);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(4);

    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2.push_back(1);
    v2.push_back(2);

    std::vector<int> v3;
    v3.push_back(4);
    v3.push_back(5);

    base.push_back(v1);
    base.push_back(v2);
    base.push_back(v3);


    std::vector<int> comb(base.size());

    print_recurssion(base,comb);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I run it it does not work let me update the code now

Comment: @Scooby the reason your code doesn't work is because you push the last 2 elements `v1.push_back(4); v1.push_back(5);` into vector v1 instead of v3. I added your code to the answer with error corrected

Comment: Okay so do you know how to make it generic so that is can take in strings and integers?

Comment: This will most likely require different approach. I suggest new ticket with detailed description of the task as it is also not quite clear what the expected output should be like.